# How much bandwidth does Vassal consume?

Tags: online, vassal

A friend of mine is designing a game, and I'd like to playtest it with him.  We have no possibility of meeting face to face; also, finding ±90 minutes to play through Vassal when I'm at home is quite difficult.  However, I travel quite often by train, and then I have much time.  The problem is, I have then only a very slow Internet connection (using my mobile phone).  Do I assume correctly that this should be enough to play through Vassal?  (I assume that it sends only info about my move - no graphics etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vassal is pretty low bandwidth - as you correctly guess, the graphics are all part of the pre-downloaded game files, so in play it only sends information about which pieces you moved and where to.  It's on the same order as using a text chat app, and pretty favourable compared to a web page.

Obviously you'll need to download and update the actual game files in advance, as those can be larger.

(There's still enough bandwidth usage that you could notice the *cost*, however, if you're on a pay-per-byte plan for your mobile.)

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is what I've expected.  I have a flat rate, so with low bandwidth it should work perfectly well for me.